# The collapsible headings in jquerymobile are being "graffitied" by errant icons

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

When I view my site's jquerymobile-driven pages (e.g. http://backpocketgrower.com/solutionppm.asp) through mobile devices, I see a peppering of jquerymobile icons throughout heading elements being used as collapsible list buttons.

I don't see the same when viewing the site through desktop browsers - where in my code should I be looking for my hitherto undetected act of stupidity?

Thanks/Bruce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After little digging I found CSS file responsible for this error:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://backpocketgrower.com/assets/css/bpg_custom.min4.css?id=140214" media="screen, projection" />
```

For some reason you have several CSS classes copied from original jQuery Mobile CSS file, classes related to icons. You should open that file and check every class having background-image:

```
background-image:url(.....
```

My best bet is:

```
background-image:url('images/icons-18-white-pack.png');
```

#### Explanation

Let me explain why I think this is a best bet. I have downloaded your web site source and recreated it locally. When viewed from my Android phone error was still there. After further source inspection using Firefox developer tools I found that 3 **CSS** files are used when displaying buttons on your page. I have removed every CSS file file by file, and error was missing when **bpg_custom.min4.css** was removed.

After that I downloaded it locally and included it instead of your file. Error was still missing. That made me think that something included in that file is causing this problem. This is because nothing included in that file don't exits in my local environment.